# give labels as a numpy array with shape(m,1) or shape(m,) to a model

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

simply i trying to test a simple Dense neural network without hidden layer.first 50th columns of my data is features and last one is label.

```
X = data[:, :50]
y = data[:, -1]
input = keras.Input(shape=(50,))
output = keras.layers.Dense(1)(input)
model = keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='mse')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=20)
```

is there difference between giving `data[:, -1]` or `data[:, 50:]` as labels to model? why? (seems the results is equal)

```
>>> data[:, 50:].shape
result: (1000, 1)

>>> data[:, -1].shape
result: (1000,)

>>> data[:, :50].shape
result: (1000, 50)
```

Comment: Could you add the values of `X.shape` and `y.shape` to your description.

Comment: i added them to description.

Comment: Try converting your label to numpy array before feeding into the network. `label = label.to_numpy()` Docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html)

Comment: there isn't any error. question is :why these create same result. now i think, in each step of  optimization, predicted value in shape of (m, 1) or (m, ) will compare with actual value with shape (m, 1) or (m, ).so there isn't any difference. this was a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

data[:, -1] returns the value of the last column for every row but data[:, 50:] will return the values of the all columns starting from column no 50.

In your case, there are only 50 columns and hence it is same as data[:, -1]

Assume that the data is of size (1000, 60), then data[:, -1] would still return a array of shape (1000,) but data[:, 50:] would return an array of shape (1000, 10)